# Flutter Future.delayed timer dispose when navigating to other page

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart, firebase-authentication

In my flutter app, I have a function that has delaye for 5 seconds to activate a button. When I navigate to other page, the timer of the delayed is still working even though I use the "pushReplacement" navigator. Can anyone help me find a way to dispose or cancel this timer when I navigate to other page.

here is the code:

```
 Future sendVerificationEmail() async {
  try{
    final user =FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    await user.sendEmailVerification();

    setState(() => canResendEmail = false);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)); // this is the line causing the error
    setState(() => canResendEmail = true);

  }catch (e) {
    Utils.showSnackBar(e.toString());
  }
  }
```

and here is the navigation button function:

```
Future<void> SignOut() async {
   await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
   Navigator.pushReplacement(
     context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  mainPage()),

   );
 }
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling `SignOut()`?

Comment: Why not use `Timer` instead of `Future.delayed`?you can cancel it.

Comment: @MendelG I have a text button that will call it: 
  TextButton(
          onPressed: () => SignOut(),
          child: const Text("Cancel"),
        ),

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak I have a button that will be disactivated for 5 seconds after each press and I thought this is the best way to do it as I saw some people online doing it this way

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak Also I have a boolen flag that will determine if the button activated or not and this boolen get disactivated when pressing the button for 5 seconds

Comment: You can use `Timer` for your case. I use it to resend otp on my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a timer instead

```dart
Timer timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    //do something here();
  });
  // You can dispose the timer like this
  timer.cancel();
```